# Rail: two models for one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

When a User buys a product, it goes to his stock. So only products in stock can be sold. Stock table has a product_id column. Simply, when a user is on products/product_id page orders must be a buy, when is on stocks/stock_id page order must be sell.

**I want to use just one table Order, and not to create two table buy_order and sell_order.**

So I created buy_order and sell_order model without migration obviously that inherit from Order model, and controllers sell_orders and buy_orders.

I just want to know if this is a correct way to go to use just one table.

My Models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
end

class BuyOrder < Order
end

class SellOrder < Order
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :buy_orders
    has_many :sell_orders
    has_many :stocks
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
end
```

My Controllers

```
class BuyOrdersController < ApplicationController

    def create
       ...
       order.type = 'buy'
       ...
    end
end

class SellOrdersController < ApplicationController

    def create
       ...
       order.type = 'sell'
       ...
    end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :buy_orders, only: [:create]
end

resources :stocks, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :sell_orders, only: [:create]
end
```

Rake Routes:

```
products_orders POST       /products/:product_id/buy_orders(.:format) orders#create
products_index GET        /products(.:format) products#index
product GET        /products/:id(.:format) products#show
stocks_orders POST       /stocks/:stock_id/sell_orders(.:format) orders#create
stocks_index GET        /stocks(.:format) stocks#index
stock GET        /stock/:id(.:format) stocks#show
```

Comment: The way to go about this is to have 1 table with a `side` column for example, where you'd save the order side (ie 'sell' / 'buy')

Comment: hi @rod check this https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as

Comment: @uzaif do you see a need for inheritance here?

Comment: This is called Single Table Inheritance (STI) and it's a common pattern. Not sure it's warranted here, if attribute sets of buy/sell orders are the same (are they?). Anyway, google this up.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the use of separating your "order" model into two distinct one. Personally, I'd chose to go for simplicity. In your order table have an attribute `side` that will be either `sell` or `buy`. A `product` would then have many `orders`, each of them belonging to a `product`.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
    has_many :stocks
end
```

You can then easily refer to the side like:

```
Product.first.orders.where(side: 'sell')
```

Would retrieve all `sell` orders for the first product record.

Comment: did this not help?